# Using cPanel through company proxy/firewall keeps resetting login

Tags: cpanel

It's really frustrating; my cPanel access keeps logging me out with an "IP address changed" message whenever I try to access it from a work computer. I'm assuming this maybe has something to do with the company's webproxy or firewalls. It's virtually impossible to get anything done, as every page refresh requires me to log in again.

Is there any way I can stop cPanel moaning about this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the security settings of the cPanel? If so, then you should disable the *Validate the IP addresses used in cookie based logins* setting, but make sure that the security tokens setting is on.